# Python pandas xlsx/ csv

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert xlsx to csv and it works, but after conversion python add ".0" to string...
Sample xlsx :

```
Name, Age
Mark, 20
```

CSV after conversion :

```
Name, Age
Mark, 20.0 <- add ".0"
```

What could the problem be?

```py
#importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 
    
# Read and store content 
# of an excel file  
read_file = pd.read_excel ("EXPORT.xlsx") 
      
# Write the dataframe object 
# into csv file 
read_file.to_csv ("data.csv",  
                  index = True, 
                  header=True,
                  encoding='utf-8-sig') 
        
# read csv file and convert  
# into a dataframe object 
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("data.csv")) 
      
# show the dataframe 
df
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce this behavior, but in my case `pd.read_excel()` automatically assigned the `int64` format on the `Age` column using the presented Excel sheet.

However this case can be easily solved with the `df.astype()` function, that can transforms data types, e.g. for your case from floating to integer format.

```py
#importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 
    
# Read and store content 
# of an excel file  
read_file = pd.read_excel ("EXPORT.xlsx") 

# transform data type of column "Age" to int64
read_file = read_file.astype({'Age': 'int64'})

# Write the dataframe object 
# into csv file 
read_file.to_csv ("data.csv",  
                  index = True, 
                  header=True,
                  encoding='utf-8-sig') 
        
# read csv file and convert  
# into a dataframe object 
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("data.csv")) 

# show the dataframe 
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added  float_format option and it seems that works

```
read_file.to_csv ("basf.csv",  
              index = None, 
              header=True,
              encoding='utf-8-sig',
              decimal=',',
              float_format='%d'
             )
```